# DataTable function works in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I have a function in my dataTable where i need to filter the table based from selected date of the user.

i have a startDate and endDate. This function works fine in chrome. But when i try it in Firefox, it won't work. what is wrong with it. Can somebody help me with this one.

this is the part where the endDate is change

```
$('#end').on('change', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var startDate = $('#start').val(),
            endDate = $('#end').val();
        filterByDate(1, startDate, endDate);
        dtv_filter.dataTable().fnDraw();
      });
```

and this is the function that filters my table.

```
var filterByDate = function(column, startDate, endDate) {
        $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
            function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
                var rowDate = normalizeDate(aData[column]),
                    start = normalizeDate(startDate),
                    end = normalizeDate(endDate);

          if (start <= rowDate && rowDate <= end) {
            return true;
          } else if (rowDate >= start && end === '' && start !== ''){
            return true;
          } else if (rowDate <= end && start === '' && end !== ''){
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        }
        );
    };

    // converts date strings to a Date object, then normalized into a YYYYMMMDDHHII format (ex: 201312201001). Makes comparing dates easier.
var normalizeDate = function(dateString) {
  var date = new Date(dateString);
  var normalized = date.getFullYear() + '' + (("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)) + '' + ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + date.getHours() + date.getMinutes();
  return normalized;
}
```

Comment: `what is wrong with it` ... I'd say `it won't work` ... supply some detail of it "not work"ing

Comment: at a guess, it's the date string format - firefox is far stricter with accepted formats than chrome

Comment: is there a format that is accepted in chrome and in firefox.? what can you suggest.?

Comment: RFC2822 format - firefox also accepts a version of ISO8601 - no idea if chrum accepts that ... what format are the date strings

Comment: now i understand.. this is because of the parsing of the date format. instead of using "-".. i tried using "/" which is accepted format in firefox as well as chrome. thanks for this information.